# Permission denied error when building Android NDK with GCC 4.7

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

In my `Application.mk` I've got the following defined:

`NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7`

But I can't get anywhere as I get the following error:

> /usr/local/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build all
>   make: execvp: /usr/local/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7: Permission denied

Anyone got any ideas? I've checked the permissions on the toolchains subfolders as well as the bin directories, and they're the same in both 4.6 and 4.7.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo) and Android NDK r8d.

I've just updated to Android NDK r8e, and the problem persists.

Comment: you are trying to run current command on Cgywin or on Ubuntu ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm running on Ubuntu.